# C Reading file and keep numbers in an array

Tags: c, arrays, loops, parsing, while-loop

I am beginner of C.

I need to read a file and keep numbers in an array. I tried for loop and while loop, but can't create the right condition. Every time I got an array with zeros when the loop meets empty lines in the file.

I tried using temp variables to assign values and then pass it to the array. And tried pass values directly to the array.

My code:

```
for (i = 0; i < (num_pt + 1);)
{
   fgets(line, 50, fp);
   if (sscanf(line,"%d%d", &tempx, &tempy))
   {
       x_cr[i] = tempx;
       y_cr[i] = tempy;

       printf("%d %d\n", x_cr[i], y_cr[i]);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: can you show the input format? you may not need to use `fgets`.

Comment: `if (sscanf(line,"%d%d", &tempx, &tempy))` needs to be `if (sscanf(line,"%d%d", &tempx, &tempy) == 2)` since the `scanf` family of functions returns the number of arguments successfully converted.

Comment: I would say `for (i = 0; i < (num_pt + 1);)` should be `for (i = 0; i < num_pt; i++)` and delete the final `i++` in the loop - this is the usual way to use a `for` loop. I am only guessing about changing the end condition, because you did not post enough code, but if for example `num_pt` is the number of points, and the number of elements, in `x_cr[]` and `y_cr[]` then indexing `x_cr[num_pt]` will be outside the bound of the array.

Comment: Moreover is is poor style and confusing to write `i < (num_pt + 1)` because the brain (and the compiler) have to perform an additional step. If that really is the end condition, the idiomatic and clear way is `i <= num_pt` and then it is easier to read, and also spot mistakes.

Comment: You should probably only increment `i` after adding an entry to your arrays, not for each line.

Comment: Mybad missed that part about empty lines.

Comment: @melpomene, thank you, the incrementation should be done inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your call to `sscanf()` could return `EOF`, `0`, `1` or `2`, and only when the result is `2` is it safe to use the values in `tempx` and `tempy`.

Consider this example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    int y;
    char *str[] = { "", "a", "1 a", "1 2" };
    enum { NUM_STR = sizeof(str) / sizeof(str[0]) };
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STR; i++)
    {
        int rc = sscanf(str[i], "%d %d", &x, &y);
        printf("rc = %2d for [%s]\n", rc, str[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When run on macOS Sierra (10.12), the output is:

```
rc = -1 for []
rc =  0 for [a]
rc =  1 for [1 a]
rc =  2 for [1 2]
```

So, your check should be:

```
if (sscanf(line,"%d%d", &tempx, &tempy) == 2)
```

Your other problem is that the `i++` should be inside the body of this `if` condition; you should only increment `i` when you add data.